# User authorization in Widevine DRM protected content for html player.

Tags: video, encryption, drm, widevine

I have studied the whole process of protecting video content with WideVine DRM. Steps I was able to achieve are:
1- Requesting content keys from widevine server
2- encrypting/packaging the content with my protection information. Generating MPEG-Encrypted content and mpd manifest file. 
3-Passing the mpd file url to the video player and setting the license url in the video player. The player then plays the encrypted content.

Now I'm wondering about very basic point. With the current setup any one have this url will be able to play the file. I want to add user authentication/authorization to the flow so that no can can play the content if only mpd url available.

I also found in widevine documentation that there is a way for implementing proxy server for this purpose but it seems complicated process.

So is there any way I can 1- prevent playing the video giving only the mpd url 2- adding user authentication/authorization level to the follow in a way easier than implementing a proxy server.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the purpose of authentication is not to authenticated mpd download. Mpd describes the content which is protected with DRM = content itself is encrypted and you need a DRM license / decryption keys to play that content. There is no value of protecting the mpd - it can be publicly available on CDN.

Authentication is used when the player finds that the content is encrypted (either from mpd, or from the stream itself). Player needs to send a license request to DRM server and that is where authentication happens.

There are in theory two options how to make sure that only selected users have playback rights (get the decryption key):

- You will use the proxy. Widevine proxy is web server which will extract any kind of authentication information and verifies that the customer has rights to play the content (eg. paid for subscription). Based on that it will either forward call to Google deployed Widevine or fail.
- You will deploy your own Widevine server and extend it to support your authentication scheme (it will most probably include just another type of proxy).

In practice, the first option is what you want to do. Second option is used mostly by huge streaming services and requires some special agreement / license from Google.

Edit: There is probably a third option - using some 3rd party solution which already have authentication build-in and allows you some kind of integration.

In either case - if you want a control over whom the license will be issued, it is server side work and it involves deploying some service.